# Ionic Angular implementing ZLib

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to use the zlib library inside a service provided in root, but when i declare the library as:

```
import * as zlib from 'zlib';
```

or

```
declare var require: any;
var zlib = require('zlib');
```

I'm getting either:
`ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ScanPageModule' before initialization` when I try to navigate to the module with component that uses this page
or a circural dependency exception.

Comment: `npm install @types/node --save-dev`

zlib is nodejs core module you will access by install types

Comment: Now I can import it, but when I try to use any method e.g. `zlib.inflate(base45Data, status => { console.log(status); }); I am gettting the same error when I try to navigate to the page that can invoke this method.
`